# Connect to a SFTP server using just the public key?

Tags: ssh

Client wants to send them files using SFTP and they just shared the username and their public key.

My understanding is that they will either need to share the username and password OR a username and a private key - is that right?

Answer (score 1):

They wouldn't (and shouldn't) share their private key.  But, you can send them *your* public key, and they can add your public key to their authorized_keys file.  This will allow you to authenticate (provided that you have the private key that corresponds to the public key that you gave them).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that we should share our public key with them vs they sending their public key and somehow expecting us to connect.

Comment: No problem.  See https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/ for a good write-up on how this works.